# How to parse a URL from string in selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

- I am using SIDE 1.3.0 along with FF 6.0.2.
- I stored a string using store text command    which contains a  "URL" by using the following command.

  storeText

which results as

```
MyCode = "<iframe src="http://myportal.com/mysales/Agent/index/4eb29642ce24e8.22143850/embedded" height="650" width="605" frameBorder="0"></iframe>"
```

I need to have only the URL part in another variable from the string above "http://myportal.com/mysales/Agent/index/4eb29642ce24e8.22334455/embedded" 
in order to proceed with the remaining test case. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>'${MyCode}'.replace(/.*src="(.*?)".*/, $1)</td>
    <td>url</td>
</tr>
```

This will use JavaScript to set a variable called `url` to the value of the `src` attribute within your `MyCode` variable.

Answer (score 1):

The first command below stores the href attribute of any element, you can modify it to your needs.

The third command uses javascript to get the pathname attribute of the DOM object.

Hope this answers your question.

If you open the IDE click on the source tab in the main window and copy and paste the code below between the  tags, you'll be able to run the test on this page, or any other stack overflow page.

```
<tr>
    <td>storeAttribute</td>
    <td>css=.profile-link@href</td>
    <td>href</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${href}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>this.browserbot.getUserWindow().document.getElementsByClassName('profile-link')[0].pathname</td>
    <td>pathname</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${pathname}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```